# How to set up a multi-language project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, javascript, html, intellij-idea

Is there a way to open/import an IntelliJ IDEA project which contains different language source files? For example I have Java (Maven) + HTML + JavaScript and, unfortunately,  I'm able to import only the Maven project. Is there a way to open/import the entire project as a single whole?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Import the project as a java project.  Then in the 'Project Structure' box, click on the module and click the + sign.  This allows you to add, e.g., a Python "facet" to the module.  I use this frequently to develop mixed Java/Python modules.

Comment: You deserve a cookie.

Comment: If this appears to not work, select the python facet and check that it has an interpreter set.  If not you can click the facet and there is a little ... to select your python executable (/usr/bin/python often works).

Comment: This seems to be a good suggestion, but directory with python code is not recognized in modules list in project structure, how to do it?

Comment: Project Structure -> Modules -> Add -> New Module -> Python -> Next -> "Select the directory with python packages" -> Finish

Comment: @greperror make sure you have the Python plugin for intellij installed and it should show up in the list of New Module options. (Settings -> Plugins -> ... )

Comment: FWIW I had to update my python plugin to see it in the list.

Comment: @d-n-ust Your comment should be added as part of the answer, it makes adding the module very clear, whereas seanmcl's answer is a little vague with the reference to "facets", I ran in circles for a while until I've read the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way of doing that.

You'll probably have to import the maven project and then add the rest of the folders, yourself, configure the correct plugins, etc.

At least that's what I do in a couple of projects where I have Java and Python source files in the mix.

Sometimes, it works even better to simply define different modules for the different types of "sub-project", especially when it's a whole different language and you happen to need to setup a compiler etc, I've ran into some problems with IntelliJ not recognizing my Python modules correctly when I mixed them up in a Java project. All went well when I created a separate module.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I considered such a way but I thought that we have some option to do this in one module.

Comment: Like I said, I don't *know* of a way, I can't guarantee for sure that there isn't some plugin or something to do that.

Comment: THe same for me. I'm creating module with Groovy and Jython files (a way to extend Apache Pig). It doesn't work :(